# Store only in Elastic AppSearch / Enterprise Search

Tags: elasticsearch, app-search, elastic-appsearch

I am trying to apply enterprise search for our e-commerce webapp.

Actually we have some fields which doesn't need to be indexed / searched, but only stored.
The schema documentation does only allow 4 types for a field:

- text
- number
- date
- geolocation

Before I try to come around indexing by falsely setting fields to geolocation or date, I wanted to ask if there are any other options to only store, but not index data into App Search?

Answer (score 0):

Documents indexed in AppSearch are visible in a dedicated indice in Elasticsearch.
As such, you can modify its mapping and reindex it or update all docs by query.
The only think I cannot tell you is the side effects incurred by such changes at appsearch level.

Best, Dan